# ¿Cómo hacer OnClick en un RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

He estado mirando cómo poner un OnClick en un RecyclerView, pero no he encontrado nada que funcione, y no funciona igual que en una ListView.

Aquí comparto el código de mi RecyclerView y a ver si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puede ser o se puede hacer para que funcione un OnClick

```
package com.example.usuario.coolmodapp.Lista;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.usuario.coolmodapp.R;

import java.util.List;

public class PcAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PcAdapter.PcViewHolder> 
{
    private List<Pc> items;

    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;

    public static class PcViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView nombre;
        public TextView precio;
        public TextView descripcion;
        public ImageView imagen;
        private String mItem;

        public PcViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            precio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
            descripcion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        }

    }

    public PcAdapter(List<Pc> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PcViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new PcViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PcViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(i).getNombre());
        viewHolder.precio.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getPrecio()));
        viewHolder.descripcion.setText(items.get(i).getDescripcion());
        viewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(items.get(i).getImagen());
    }
}
```

---

Código con un intento de implementar un OnClick.

```
package com.example.usuario.coolmodapp.Lista;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.usuario.coolmodapp.R;

import java.util.List;

public class PcAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PcAdapter.PcViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private List<Pc> items;

    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;


    public static class PcViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView nombre;
        public TextView precio;
        public TextView descripcion;
        public ImageView imagen;
        private String mItem;

        public PcViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            precio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
            descripcion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        }

    }

    public PcAdapter(List<Pc> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new PcViewHolder(//Aqui da un error o pide algo que no se exactamente lo que es);

    @Override
    public PcViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)// No detecta mContext

                .inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout, viewGroup, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        return new PcViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPositio(v);

        String item = mList.get(itemPosition);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//No detecta mRecyclerView, mList y mContext (Cannot resolve symbol)

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PcViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(i).getNombre());
        viewHolder.precio.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getPrecio()));
        viewHolder.descripcion.setText(items.get(i).getDescripcion());
        viewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(items.get(i).getImagen());
    }
}
```

Comment: El codigo que he compartido es del RecyclerView normal que funciona, solo que quiero implementar un OnClick pero el RecyclerView no lleva esa funcion incorporada como los ListView. Lo que he visto era alguna solucion de usuarios en  el stackoverflow ingles, y lo que he probado no llega a funcionar

Comment: Alguno que he probado da errores, y el único que va sin errores al ejecutar la APP y hacer algún Click en la lista no hace nada

Comment: Hola Cristian, esas variables que dices, `mList`, `mRecyclerView` y `mContext` no las tienes incializadas en el codigo presentado.. de donde salen?  (recuerda eliminar los comentarios anteriores, que son obsoletos) Un saludo

Comment: Buenas, te comparto el link de donde he encontrado esa solucion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick es lo primero de todo, alomejor me falta inicializar esas 3 variables, voy a ver

Comment: (la linea con `getChildLayoutPositio` le falta una "n" al final no?)

Comment: Si lo he visto ahora, pero sigue todo igual.

Comment: Las 3 variables, no se exactamente como tengo que iniciarlizarlas

Answer (score 4):

Yo lo que suelo hacer para implementar el `OnClick` en un `RecyclerView` es utilizar la función [addOnItemTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnItemTouchListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener)), esta función no está en el adapter sino es una función propia del `RecyclerView` y la debes utilizar cuando estás definiendo tu `RecyclerView`.

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo, espero que te sirva de ayuda:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listaLibros);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new PcAdpater(pcs));

    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MyActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {            
        @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        } 
    });

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                try {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                    if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                        int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);

                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"The Item Clicked is: "+ position ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: funciona para cuando solo haces scroll tambien, genial!, gracias al if solo se activa cuando haces click (touch)

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido de ayuda!

Answer (score 4):

Define una `interfaz` lugar de que tu `Adapter` implemente `View.OnClickListener`, crea la interfaz:

```
import android.view.View;

public interface  RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener {

    void onClick(View v, int position);
}
```

Cuando definas el Adapter, define como parámetro la interface:

```
// recyclerView.setAdapter(new PcAdpater(pcs));

recyclerView.setAdapter(new PcAdpater(pcs, new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, int position) {

             //***Aquí realizaras tu acción! :)

            }
        }));
```

En cuanto a tu Adapter elimina que implemente `View.OnClickListener` y modifica su constructor para que reciba además de los datos el listener:

```
public class PcAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PcAdapter.PcViewHolder> { //implements View.OnClickListener {

private RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener recyclerViewOnItemClickListener;    

...
...
/*public PcAdapter(List<Pc> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }*/

        public PcAdapter(List<Pc> items,  @NonNull RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener
                recyclerViewOnItemClickListener) {
            this.items = items;
            this.recyclerViewOnItemClickListener = recyclerViewOnItemClickListener;
        }
```

Como último cambio en tu clase estatica "holder" implementa el método `onClick()`:

```
public static class PcViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { //implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView nombre;
    public TextView precio;
    public TextView descripcion;
    public ImageView imagen;
    private String mItem;

    public PcViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        precio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
        descripcion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    }

    //Implementa!
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       recyclerViewOnItemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }

}
```

De esta forma cuando definas el adapter ahí podría realizar la acción que deseas para el `onClick()` :

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(new PcAdpater(pcs, new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v, int position) {

                 //***Aquí realizaras tu acción! :)

                }
            }));
```

ejemplo completo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Horizontal-ListView

Comment: Vale ya tengo todo el codigo puesto y sin ningun error, he puesto que cuando doy click se abra una nueva Pantalla, pero no hace nada.

Answer (score 2):

hace un tiempo estuve necesitando lo mismo pero no encontré nada que satisficiera mi necesidad, por lo que tuve que hacer lo siguiente:

```
inventoryViewHolder.idTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Datos: "+datos.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Por ejemplo, yo quería que cuando tocara el registro mostrara datos adicionales que no se podían ver en la lista. Lo que hice fue ponerle un evento a uno de los textViews que conforman el registro.

Comment: Interesante alternativa, gracias